# yeoman + php framework integration

Tags: laravel, yeoman

Does anyone know how to integrate a yeoman deploy with

a php framework skeleton (may be laravel) without using the php frontend

as external domain ?

I found this [generator-laravel](https://github.com/Freyskeyd/generator-laravel)

I'd like to know your opinion or hint about this case.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without using the php frontend". But I've just managed to get the yeoman "webapp" generated front-end working with Laravel (grunt, bower, twitter bootstrap, jquery and modenizr). If that's of interest I can answer with details.

Comment: @scipilot I'm not the OP, but I'm interested to know what you did to integrate the two.

Answer (score 3):

I installed "yeo webapp" and Laravel 4 via composer next to each other. I then manually integrated the contents of the webapp www folder into Laravel's structure. (I'm wondering now if there's an automated, repeatable way to do this, as it felt a bit one-way, but I think all the Bower packages are still updatable. I guess as Yeoman is a generator, it is one-way.).

These files are moved from webapp/www into Laravel root folder:

```
.bowerrc     [modified below]
.jshint
bower.json
Gruntfile.js [modified below]
package.json
```

The Grunt-built contents of webapp/www/dist is equivalent to the Laravel/public folder, so we need an equivalent of the sources in webapp/www/app. For this I created a Laravel/public-src folder. I modified the build to read from this src folder and built into the Laravel/public folder. the public-src folder contains a merge of the webapp front-end sources and the Laravel entry point (index.php, .htaccess).

*NB. the Laravel/public folder will get completely destroyed when you build! So please attend to any uncommitted files before running grunt. Make sure all your previous static resources are moved over to the src folder.*

.bowerrc becomes:

```
{
    "directory": "public-src/bower_components"
}
```

Gruntfile changes are:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // configurable paths
    yeoman: {
        app: 'public-src',
        dist: 'public'
    },
:
```

So this should allow you to build your SASS, JS etc into the Laravel public folder. But this isn't much use beyond a static HTML site, which you're obviously not building or we wouldn't be bothering with Laravel. So we need to publish part of the front-end build into the Laravel views sub folder.

This is a simplified version, which just does all files with the naming convention of something-view.php but I'm presuming your Laravel app will be using a master-template (header/footer) structure and thus the front-end build should only be publishing the outer views, not all the sub-views (page bodies or modules).

home-view.php here is the php-ised version of the webapp HTML, with any PHP placeholders you need.

Gruntfile changes to do this post-build publish into Laravel views, and supporting PHP files instead of HTML, are:

```
    'bower-install': {
        app: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/home-view.php',
            ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
        }
    },
```

...

```
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/*-view.php'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*-view.php'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
```

...

```
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*-view.php',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
```

...

```
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
    ...
        // move the main view(s) into Laravel
        laravel: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                dest: 'app/views',
                src: '*-view.php'
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: 'index.php'
            }]
        }
    },
```

...

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
...
    'usemin',
    'copy:laravel'
]);
```

I also added some build-output exclusions to Laravel/.gitignore

```
.tmp
.sass-cache
public/bower_components
public/scripts
public/styles
public-src/bower_components
```

(Although I've since read it's [recommended](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) to keep a cached copy of your installed packages i.e. public-src/bower_components).

That's pretty much it, apologise if I've missed anything, but there's still more to tune. e.g. I will probably remove the wildcard PHP publishing, in favour of publishing just the header/footer master-template views as mentioned. The rest of the internal/body views can be sourced from the Laravel/views folder and won't need to be built for front-end purposes.

I do intend to fork my codebase, remove proprietary code and produce a clean base of a working integration which I can share. Until then this is all I can offer. I hope its of some help.

Comment: [http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/](This article) is a much clearer description of using almost the same front-end components with Laravel, than I could write.